# JSplitPane propertyChange event in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane, propertychangelistener

I am creating a `JSplitPane` in Java Swing. I am adding `PropertyChangeListener` with split pane.
Property change method is being called when I start to drag the divider but I want to call the method when I drop the divider after dragging , how is it possible?

I am using the following code:

```
 splitpane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, 
     new PropertyChangeListener() {
      @Override
       public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pce) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Change " +panel.getSize().width);
    }
  });
```

The above method shows the width of panel before dragging but I want the width after dragging.

Comment: *"I want the width after dragging"*  Why?  What application feature do you wish to offer the user by doing so?

Comment: Are you certain you do not get a `PropertyChangeEvent` when you stop dragging ? Try replacing that `JOptionPane#showMessageDialog` with a regular `System.out`. Not sure how the message dialog will influence the events which go to the split pane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the divider location is set before the contained components are laid out by the splitpane `LayoutManager`.

The solution is quite easy, you can simply wrap your call in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`. An alternative would be to add a `ComponentListener` to each component contained in the splitpane.

Small example of code:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker.StateValue;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class TestSplitPaneDragging {

    protected void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle(TestSplitPaneDragging.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(new JTextArea(24, 48));
        splitPane.setRightComponent(new JTextArea(24, 48));
        splitPane.addPropertyChangeListener(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.err.println(splitPane.getLeftComponent().getWidth());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        frame.add(splitPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestSplitPaneDragging().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```